# Azure Queue-Triggered Function without Deleting the Message

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'd like to be informed of new items being added to a queue. I don't necessarily want the items to be deleted from the queue. Is this possible? I don't want to return a failure response from the function.

Of course, I can poll the queue myself, if I have no other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't necessarily want the items to be deleted from the queue. Is this possible?

AFAIK this is not possible, Whenever azure queue triggered function triggers the message gets processed by function due to which the messages gets deleted. And this is the behavior of this trigger .

[image]

Alternative ways are to send these messages to another queue where a trigger is not integrated with it.

Another way is to send this message to a blob and append it next messages to know what all messages got queued later.